# How do I update my Fragment after data modification in my activity (SQLite)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-sqlite

I have a ListView in a Fragment that is populated when the app starts.
I put a ParcelableArrayList in a Bundle in my newInstance method, and I get it back in my OnCreateView after passing the ArrayList in the newInstance method in my Activity (which is the data read from the SQLite database).

This part works, as I display my data in my Fragment correctly.

I implemented a button that removes all data from the table, and I would now like to update my view after I cleaned the table.
The remove all button is handled in my main activity where I call my database handler to empty the table.

What is the best way to do that ? Here are the parts of the code that seem relevant to me :

My Fragment class :

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String RECETTES_KEY = "recettes_key";
    private List<Recette> mRecettes;
    private ListView mListView;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MainFragment newInstance(List<Recette> r) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList(RECETTES_KEY, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) r);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRecettes = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(RECETTES_KEY);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        configureListView();
    }

    // Configure ListView
    private void configureListView(){
        this.mListView = getView().findViewById(R.id.activity_main_list_view);
        RecetteAdapter adapter = new RecetteAdapter(getContext(), mRecettes);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Relevant parts from my Main acivity :
This is in my OnCreate method :

```
mDatabaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
mRecettes = mDatabaseHandler.readRecettes();
mDatabaseHandler.close();
```

This is in the method I use to show a fragment :

```
if (this.mMainFragment == null) this.mMainFragment = MainFragment.newInstance(mRecettes);
this.startTransactionFragment(this.mMainFragment);
```

Let me know if I should add more of my code, this is my first time posting :)
Lucile

Comment: you're saying there is button which deletes all the data and you want to delete that data from the UI too , right?

Comment: I want my UI to be updated and display nothing since I emptied the database. It should work too if I add an element or just remove one from my database. I want the UI to be constantly coherent with the contents of my database

Comment: call notifydatasetChanged() on your adapter after you change the data inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `R.layout.fragment_main`, you can add an id to the root view, say with `android:id@+id/fragment_root`

And whenever you want to change the fragment view:

In activity:

```
MainFragment fragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentById(R.id.fragment_root);
fragment.updateList(mRecettes);
```

And then create the new method `updateList()` in your `MainFragment`

```
public void updateList(List<Recette> recettes) {
    mRecettes.clear();
    mRecettes.addAll(recettes);
    configureListView();
}
```

Also you can tag your fragment when you add it to your transaction instead of using its id, and then use `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentByTag()`

Comment: Hi Zain and thank you for your response. I added an id to the root container of my main fragment's xml (it's a FrameLayout). I implemented the update method in the fragment but when i call the method from the activity I get a null fragment. Also, I had to replace :
MainFragment fragment = (MainFragment) getFragmentManager().getFragmentById(R.id.fragment_root);
with
MainFragment fragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main_root);

Does this seem right to you ?

Comment: @LucileBellamy sorry, my fault for using deprecated getFragmentManager(); sure use getSupportFragmentManager() instead; did you get NPE on configureListView()?

Comment: I had a NPE on fragment.updateList(mRecettes);
fragment is null.

Comment: @LucileBellamy Can you please try to use the tag instead of the fragment's id `getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()              
        .add(R.id.fragment_main_root, fragment, "someTag")
        .commit();`
then use `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentByTag()` to get the fragment

Comment: @LucileBellamy most welcome .. If my answer was useful, please click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way help others who have similar questions.